# Session variable is not remaining set

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Basically I am trying to set a session variable as a boolean to ensure a user cannot complete a function twice.

```
session_start()
if(isset($_GET['vote'], $_GET['title'], $_GET['user']))
{
    if(isset($_SESSION[$_GET['title']]))
    {
        $_SESSION[$_GET['title']] = true;
    }
    else if(!isset($_SESSION[$_GET['title']]))
    {
        $_SESSION[$_GET['title']] = false;
        add_title_vote($_GET['title'], $_GET['vote'], $_GET['user']);
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to take the information that was sent in a `get` method, then based on the one get variable, title, a new session variable is created. If the session variable already existed, it is supposed to set the variable to `true`. If the variable did not exist, the session variable is set to false and a function dependent on the value of the session variable is called. The function is only called if the session variable is `false`.

The function called if the session variable is `false`:

```
function add_title_vote($title, $vote, $user)
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "Assignments";
    $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($_SESSION[$title] == false)
    {
    if($vote === 'up')
    {
    $sql = "UPDATE `mi4` SET `relevance` = `relevance` + 1 WHERE `title`='$title'";
    $servername1 = "localhost";
    $username1 = "root";
    $password1 = "";
    $dbname1 = "Users";
    $connection1 = new mysqli($servername1, $username1, $password1, $dbname1);
    mysqli_query($connection1, "UPDATE `login` SET `score` = `score` + 1 WHERE `user` = '$user'");
    }
    else if ($vote === 'down' && $votedown[$title] == false)
    {
    $sql = "UPDATE `mi4` SET `relevance` = `relevance` - 1 WHERE `title`='$title'";
    $servername1 = "localhost";
    $username1 = "root";
    $password1 = "";
    $dbname1 = "Users";
    $connection1 = new mysqli($servername1, $username1, $password1, $dbname1);
    mysqli_query($connection1, "UPDATE `login` SET `score` = `score` - 1 WHERE `user` = '$user'");
    }
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $_SESSION['voted'] = true;
    header("Location: /mi4.php");
    die();
    $_SESSION[$title] = true;
    }
}
```

For some reason it always says that the session variable has not been set, and executes the else if portion of the if statement in the first snippet of code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` before you start referencing session vars? Must be present in all scripts making session var references.

Comment: Yes, `session_start()` is in the code above what is given.

Comment: `$_SESSIONS` is not a superglobal variable, but you seem to be treating it as one. You want `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Woops, that was a typo. I changed the SESSIONS to SESSION. Unfortunately the code still does not work. The function either will not call at all or can be called infinitely.

Comment: So you have still the problem or is it solved with this typo? Also if the function is in another file make sure to start your session there as well

Comment: The typo did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are the two codes in the same file?

Answer (score 1):

You've written `die()` before you set the session:

```
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $_SESSION['voted'] = true;
    header("Location: /mi4.php");
    die(); <--
    $_SESSION[$title] = true; 
    }
}
```

You can either remove it or put it after session. Both ways you don't need it because you're not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and past this. It works.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['vote'], $_GET['title'], $_GET['user']))
{
    if(isset($_SESSION[$_GET['title']]))
    {
        $_SESSION[$_GET['title']] = true;
    }
    else if(!isset($_SESSION[$_GET['title']]))
    {
        $_SESSION[$_GET['title']] = false;
        add_title_vote($_GET['title'], $_GET['vote'], $_GET['user']);
    }
}
```